# What is the character `bia` in `bia响`?

Tags: characters

In this video [方清平《春节记事》单口相声笑侃春节趣闻轶事](https://youtu.be/7xtbsifwLqQ?t=4m45s) there's a short part of a sentence at around ~4:46 where the speaker says:

> 往地一摔 bia响了

The subtitles themselves leave out `bia` and just go for:

> 往地一摔 响了

I went through [北京话词典](http://gongjushu.cnki.net/refbook/R201506105.html) but it just goes from:

- [避屈 bìqū](http://gongjushu.cnki.net/refbook/detail.aspx?db=crfd&RECID=R2015061050000500)

to

- [边边儿沿沿儿 biānbiānryán yánr](http://gongjushu.cnki.net/refbook/detail.aspx?db=crfd&RECID=R2015061050000502)

In other dialects I've seen `bia` written: 扁、瘪 and .

I've seen 嘌 noted as "pia" it might be an option with the confusion of b/p.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps there is no such character.

Comment: As native Beijing'er, I believe it's 吧. When we see 吧 as in 吧唧 or 吧的一声 in words, we would naturally read aloud as bia1.

Comment: Modern Chinese writing system and Pinyin can only be applied to 
 standard Mandarin. Although you ARE able find corresponding character for most words in any Chinese language because of their origin. But you'll still see lots of words that can't be written down with characters, just like this one. Notice that people can also invent ANOTHER writing system using Chinese characters to write languages other than Mandarin, you can see many such examples in Cantonese speaking area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two characters that have the pronunciation `bia`:

> 拼音bia4
>
> ㈠邑名。
>
> ㈡姓。

> ㈠bia4,上下相付。

---

[zdic](http://bbs.zdic.net/thread-198531-1-1.html) has a question that reads:

> 从小有个朋友问我“bia”拼出来的汉字怎么写，我当时真懵了，不会啊！时间过去20年了，突然回想起这个拼音，有会写的么，请告知，谢谢了

the last comment says:

> 8楼14楼是权威说法。

Number eight reads:

> pia、bia、diang，其实就是pa、ba、dang的变读。
>
> 方法是在声母与韵母间插入“i ” 。
>
> 例子太多了，就不列举了。

and number fourteen says:

> 多以“吧”字代之。如吧叽，吧嗒。吧读bia.

《哈尔滨方言词典》p. 110

> [image: yup]

Simply lists all `bia`:

> □

but the same words from the zdic thread are written as:

> 吧叽

and

> 吧嗒

Seemingly making **吧** an acceptable candidate.

---

《北京方言词典》陈刚 商务印书馆 1985 p.17 confirms this assumption:

> [image]

Comment: 墙都不扶, 就扶你. bia都能研究这么深.

Comment: @Jacob Please upvote if you haven't then! :)

Comment: @user3306356 . 厉害厉害，优秀！

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Please upvote if you like it!

Comment: @user3306356 . Really like it! I have upvoted it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's 象声词， which sounds funny to the most people from the northeast. Refer to this link for [pia](https://m.baidu.com/from=1086k/bd_page_type=1/ssid=0/uid=0/pu=usm%401%2Csz%40320_1002%2Cta%40iphone_2_7.0_2_7.3/baiduid=FF22DF561569F3860E45C40E2A747D99/w=0_10_/t=iphone/l=3/tc?ref=www_iphone&lid=9536953789412652404&order=1&fm=alop&tj=www_normal_1_0_10_title&vit=osres&m=8&srd=1&cltj=cloud_title&asres=1&nt=wnor&title=%E5%B0%8F%E6%B2%88%E9%98%B3%E5%8F%A3%E5%A4%B4%E7%A6%85%E6%88%90%E4%BB%8A%E5%B9%B4%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%80%E7%83%AD%E8%AF%8D%E4%B8%93%E5%AE%B6%E5%8F%8D%E5%AF%B9%E5%86%8D%E9%80%A0%E5%AD%97(%E5%9B%BE)_%E5%A8%B1%E4%B9%90...&dict=32&wd=&eqid=845a10f14941b800100000005afd1f12&w_qd=IlPT2AEptyoA_yk5z35byQi6F6ZUmIYnuVYYcPnTtBu&tcplug=1&sec=29838&di=e91d8fcc32b1e5b8&bdenc=1&tch=124.0.286.193.0.0&nsrc=IlPT2AEptyoA_yixCFOxXnANedT62v3IIxiJ_yVS2zSt95qshbWxBd6eXTv6NWyJZpPPuW3HfsFUbiCu0VByj2YKh4A0sWkf9l0ddenq6RO_CBZbeAFiPgTxGGwryPjzk_&clk_info=%7B%22srcid%22%3A1599%2C%22tplname%22%3A%22www_normal%22%2C%22t%22%3A1526538017957%2C%22xpath%22%3A%22div-a-h3%22%7D&sfOpen=1). Bia is often used to take the same effect I think. Ex. Bia ji, bia ji. == Pia ji pia ji. Those are very interesting 象声词, and never seen them being written out. But gua ji gua ji could be written as 呱唧呱唧 I think, meaning 鼓掌 clapping.

Answer (score -1):

The joke was about throwing firecracker

The term "噼里啪啦" is used to mimic sound of a string of firecrackers explodes

> https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%99%BC%E9%87%8C%E5%95%AA%E5%95%A6/1623777
>
> *例句:*
>
> *过年了，外面鞭炮声**噼里啪啦**响个不停*

You might had heard "啪" (Pā) there  (he was making a sound effect of  a single firecracker explodes, Therefore, he didn't say "噼里啪啦" but just "啪")

> "往地一摔, '啪' (一声地), 响了"

Another character 嘭 (Pēng) can also be used for mimicking the sound of firecracker.

*Or there's no character at all. Anyway, it is just a noise that has no meaning on it's own*